# Applying plone.app.caching operation on your view's HTTP response in Plone

Tags: plone

I have a custom view returning a JSON payload for AJAX:

```
class DataSource(grok.CodeView):
    """
    Generate JSON array needed to populate the fields
    """
    grok.context(ISiteRoot)
    grok.name("dgftreeselect-test-data")

    def render(self):
        self.request.response.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
        return json.dumps(SAMPLE_DATA)
```

I'd like to apply plone.app.caching's *moderateCaching* operation on the resulting HTTP response.

What would be the shortest and most beautiful way to express my intent in Python?

And if it's simpler... then just saying directly "cache in browser/front-end proxy for 24 hours".

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this in ZCML, e.g.

```
  <cache:rulesetType
      name="my.package.DataSource"
      title="My data source view"
      description="Contains data stuff"
      />

  <cache:ruleset
    ruleset="my.package.DataSource"
    for=".browser.DataSource"
    />
```

You then use either the Plone UI or a registry.xml import to map my.package.DataSource to the operations you want (e.g. moderate caching).

See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.caching/2.0a1 for how to define rulesets and map views to them; http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.caching for how to manage Plone's rulesets.

Comment: I tried to export Caching Policies under portal_setup but it results to an empty file: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="caching_policy_manager" meta_type="CMF Caching Policy Manager"/> - is there example anyhere how to use GenericSetup XML to map operations to data sources?

Comment: I see the same.  I wonder if that export only works when you are still using CacheSetup.  Instead, you should export the plone.app.registry settings ("Export the configuration registry schemata" in portal_setup) and look for the plone.app.caching settings there.  The one you are looking for is mostly the operationMapping field.

Comment: Note that you do not need to define your own rulesetType. If the default plone.app.caching rulesetTypes are good enough for you, then you can specify for example ruleset plone.content.itemView in the cache:ruleset in Martin's answer.